# QgsDefaultValue depending on another default value doesn't update

Tags: pyqgis

I set the default value of two fields in the same table as follows:

```
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('FieldA')
layerLandwirt.setDefaultValueDefinition(idx, QgsDefaultValue('$area',True))
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('FieldB')
layerLandwirt.setDefaultValueDefinition(idx, QgsDefaultValue('"FieldA"-"FieldC"',True))
```

`FieldB` doesn’t properly update if I do edit-"split features" and cut a polygon in two parts. Only one of the two new polygon parts updates `FieldA` and `FieldB`. The other part only updates `FieldA`.
How can I make it to update FieldB automatically as well?

I’d like `FieldA` and `FieldB` to update like ShapeArea in a ArcGIS GDB.

`FieldC` is another integer field in the same table.

Comment: It looks like that is a bug.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I did not change anything. Maybe I just wasn’t aware that FieldC doesn’t change and did a miscalculation or something really made the code running.

Comment: I tested this issue. absolutely there is a problem. QGIS desn't update FieldB properly.